# Select specific text from a TextBox on Tapped event

Tags: c#, uwp

This is a UWP app.

I'm trying to select text with a single tap while having buttons that allow a user to differentiate if they want to select a word, sentence, paragraph, or page. I can get the pointer position and the text inside the textbox but I can't find any reasonable way to associate the two.

Is there a property or method that I'm missing which will allow me to get perhaps an index position in the textbox where the pointer currently is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have anything selected currently (SelectionLength = 0), then the SelectionStart Property will return the index of the item that matches your cursor position.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.selectionstart?view=winrt-20348